# What is the status of Java superpackages?

Tags: java, java-7

In [JSR 294](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=294) the superpackage feature for Java is specified. It should debut in Java 7, but the JSR is marked as inactive and Java 7 was released half a year ago.

Definite information on superpackages are somewhat hard to come by on the net, there are numerous articles on the 'upcoming superpackages', but hardly any on the current state of the feature. So my question is: What is the status of the feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it is now called modules and should be part of <strike>Java 8</strike> Java 9 - you can find more information [in JSR 337](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=337) (search for module on the page). Modules are covered by [Project Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/).

Comment: The approach has changed from superpackages to modules, so it's not obvious, that this is the answer. Modules supercede superpackages, by providing the same functionality and achieving more besides with respect to dependencies and restructuring of the JDK.