# Do super-packages exist in Java 7?

Tags: java, java-7

I would like to know if super-packages as they were introduced 
in JSR number XXX exist in Java 7 ?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean but could it be this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102529/what-is-the-status-of-java-superpackages

Comment: Since Java 7 has been released quite some time ago you could have checked the release notes by yourself. So far for "what have you tried".